# npm install from GitHub in specific environment

Tags: node.js, github, installation, npm

My team uses a private npm registry. We install packages from this private registry when developing locally and when deploying to production. When deploying to *staging*, however, we'd like to pull from GitHub instead. I thought this would be possible using a `preinstall` script which rewrites **package.json** to use the appropriate git+ssh:// URLs in place of the version numbers if NODE_ENV=staging.

This appears not to work, possibly because npm ignores the changes made to **package.json** (having already required it).

Perhaps I'm going about this in completely the wrong way. What is the recommended way of achieving this?

Comment: Write a shell script for this: (1) pull packages from github to local folders; (2) Run `npm install <folder>` to install the packages.

Comment: Why can't you tell NPM to install directly from the repository? `npm install <repository-url>`

Comment: @HenryMerriam: We only want to install directly from the repository when NODE_ENV=staging. In all other environments, we want to install the specified version of each package from our private npm registry. Switching the behaviour based on context is difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try running `npm-install`, which will resolve and install all of your dependencies, then `npm-shrinkwrap`, which will generate the file `npm-shrinkwrap.json`.

You can run your pre-install script on `npm-shrinkwrap.json` and insert 'git+ssh://' URL's as needed, which already has all of the resolved dependencies you need. This should give you a shrink-wrapped package.json file which points to your github repositories.

Check out https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-shrinkwrap.html#Building-shrinkwrapped-packages for more info on shrink-wrapping.

Comment: Thanks, @Stankalank! The JSON structure generated by `npm shrinkwrap` should be fairly easy to traverse. I just hope that npm looks for __npm-shrinkwrap.json__ *after* running preinstall scripts. I'll create a simple test case to find out.

Comment: Having a preinstall script generate and rewrite __npm-shrinkwrap.json__ does in fact work. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use two different `package.json` files, one for staging and one for development and production. These files can be stored on the corresponding SCM branches.

You can specify dependencies for `npm` in many ways.

### Git URL

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "private_dependency": git://user@hostname:project.git#ref
  }
}
```

Simply supply the URL to the dependency. `#ref` is a git reference. If you omit this it will default to `master`.

### GitHub URL

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "private_dependency": user/project
  }
}
```

### Tarball URL

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "private_dependency": example.com/tarball.tar.gz
  }
}
```

[For more information about supported formats see here.](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/json.html#dependencies)

Comment: "You can use two different `package.json` files, one for staging and one for development and production." -- How can I have two different files named package.json in the same directory?

Comment: I assume that you are using some kind of Source Code Management. `git`, subversion, mercurial? In your staging and development branch use one `package.json` in the production branch use the other.

Comment: We don't currently have separate branches for staging and production, but this is an option we should consider. It'd add complexity to our development process, but it may be necessary to support a continuous integration server.

Comment: [I have opened an issue in the `npm` issue tracker.](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5008)

Answer (score 1):

Having a setup similar to yours, we are using [roco](https://www.npmjs.org/package/roco) to run various tasks such as old-tags-cleanup, test-run, etc. If configured properly, it will come down to `roco staging deploy` and `roco production deploy` :)

Answer (score 0):

For private repository you have to put it under dependencies.

```
{
    "private": true
    "name": "foo",
    "dependencies": {
        "private-repo": "git+ssh://gitolite@my.server:my/project",
    }
    [...]
}
```